# How exactly do eval and exec interact with __future__?

Tags: python, eval

I want to know how `__future__` imports interact with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (and [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile), I guess).

Experimentation (with python 2) shows that module-level `__future__` imports do have an effect on code executed by `eval` and `exec`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(1, end='!\n')
eval(r"print(2, end='!\n')")
exec r"print(3, end='!\n')"
```

Output:

```
1!
2!
3!
```

But at the same time, code executed with `exec` can perform its own `__future__` imports that only affect the code locally:

```
print 1
exec r"from __future__ import print_function; print(2, end='!\n')"
print 3
exec r"print 4"
```

Output:

```
1
2!
3
4
```

But experimentation can only get you so far. My questions are:

- Are these interactions well-defined and documented?
- Is there a way to *disable* module-level `__future__` imports in `eval`, `exec` and `compile`?

Comment: There's some discussion of this on the Python mailing list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-October/146573.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements):

> Code compiled by calls to the built-in functions `exec()` and `compile()`
>   that occur in a module `M` containing a future statement will, by
>   default, use the new syntax or semantics associated with the future
>   statement.

You can disable this behaviour in [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile):

> The optional arguments *flags* and *dont_inherit* control which future
>   statements (see [PEP 236](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236)) affect the compilation of *source*.

For example:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('foo', 'bar')
foo bar
>>> code1 = compile("print('foo', 'bar')", "<string>", "exec")
>>> exec(code1)
foo bar
>>> code2 = compile("print('foo', 'bar')", "<string>", "exec", dont_inherit=True)
>>> exec(code2)
('foo', 'bar')
```

The other way around, disabling the usage of `__future__` imports in arbitrary code being executed/compiled, is not possible as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with _"disabling the usage of `__future__` imports in arbitrary code being executed/compiled, is not possible"_. Are you talking about preventing `exec` from executing its own `__future__` imports? Or are you saying that it's not possible to disable module-level `__future__` imports in `exec` without manually compiling the code with `compile` first?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I was saying that you can't prevent code being executed or compiled from executing its own `__future__` imports, but it is **also** not possible to disable those module-level imports in `exec`!